# Sortable table accessible to keyboard users

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility

I have a `<thead>` with a couple of rows that are sortable. My markup currently looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <th class="table-head__cell table-head__cell-sortable">
        <span class="table-head__text">Date</span>
        <i class="icon fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </th>
    <th class="table-head__cell align-right table-head__cell-sortable">
        <span class="table-head__text">Value</span>
        <i class="icon fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </th>
</tr>
```

I want the sortable columns to be keyboard accessible. I ask myself if would it be better to add a `tabindex="0"` and `aria-role="button"` to the `.table-head__cell`. Or wrap a `<button>` around the content of `<th>` element.

I am aware of that you should use the correct semantic elements over aria roles but it feels a bit weird to me to add a button inside the `<th>`.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this or something to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only give one ARIA `role` to an element. So it's impossible to give both the `heading` role and the `button` role.

If you write:

```
 <th role="button">
```

The `th` element will no longer be an heading, and will become a button.

The solution to put the `button` element inside the `th` is the remaining solution.

Comment: OK my intension was to do one or the other. Putting a `<button>` inside the `<th>` would be the most ideal solution to me as it seems to be valid.